# Django - models.ForeignKey Giving error that mentions class is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite

I am developing a Student management system in django and while making it I got this

```
class Dept(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='X')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and while doing make migrations I get this error
by what means Can I get this right and how can I tackle this error

```
    (studentmanagementsystem) C:\Users\harsh\dev\student management\student_management>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\harsh\dev\student management\student_management\student_app\models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Dept(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\dev\student management\student_management\student_app\models.py", line 18, in Dept
    class Course(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\dev\student management\student_management\student_app\models.py", line 19, in Course
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'Dept' is not defined

(studentmanagementsystem) C:\Users\harsh\dev\student management\student_management>
```

Comment: Are both of these classes in the same file?

Comment: yes, they are in same file

Comment: Try this: `dept = models.ForeignKey('student_app.Dept', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, assuming the app name where this model resides in `student_app`.

Comment: ```You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'dept' to course without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:      '''  I am getting this now

Comment: If you don't have any data in the `Dept` model, you can just give it any number.

Comment: can you help how can I do it, Actually I am new to django.

Comment: I have posted the answer below. Regarding the one-off default, do you have any data in your `Dept` department in the database?

Comment: Thanks!! its working perfectly now and doesnt show any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I do not know why you were getting this error as what you have shown here in the example is correct. The only times (at least that I know of) you get this error is when:

1. The two models are defined in different files and there is a problem with importing the relationship model.
2. The model that the relationship is being created with is defined *after* the relationship. In your example, it would mean defining the `Dept` model after the `Course` model.

You can import your models as a string using `APP_NAME.MODEL_NAME`, which avoids such cases, specially the second scenario I have described.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # Assuming your model resides in an app called 'student_app'
    dept = models.ForeignKey('student_app.Dept', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```